# My first jig saw; is this blade fitted right? Black & Decker BDEJS600C

Tags: powertools, saw

Just purchased a jig saw for minor renovation work, Black & Decker BDEJS600C. Came with a single blade (116-1 HCS), trying to fit the darn thing in its holder, but something doesn't look right. Followed these instructions (right from manual)

- Push locking lever away from shoe
- insert shank of blade into holder (teeth facing forward)
- release lever

I've done this 10 times; the blade appears to be fitted and locked (I cannot remove it by hand), but the lower part of the blade is angled forward, and the quick release latch is pointing up, not too far from its "release" position. I'm concerned because these conditions are not consistent with the photo on the box or the instruction manual; in those photos, the saw blade is perpendicular with the shoe (it's not angled), and the release latch is in a much safer position, pointing down, not up.

### Question

Is the position of the stock blade normal?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I realize this post is 6 years old, but just wanted to add a follow-up. I purchased the same model jigsaw, and discovered the same issue: the blade is not quite vertical, it slopes forward at the bottom. I found this StackExchange post while looking into it.

I contacted B&D, showed them a photo similar to yours, and they sent a replacement. The replacement has the same issue. So this is either as-designed, or a flaw in the model. Unfortunately many of their marketing pics show the blade as vertical which is misleading. Not sure how you're supposed to make clean cuts with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No worries, the blade on your saw does not simply move in a vertical path. It is designed to "orbit", which means as it travels up and down it also "orbits" forward and backward. B&D claims that this design has some benefits, including easier cutting of curves. On your saw the orbit action is adjustable.

Your blade and latch look different than on the box because the saw action just happens to be on the forward portion of the orbit. If you trigger it and let it stop again it will be on some other random angle, or may be vertical as shown on the box.

Comment: ... and if the blade pings off in use, then you did it wrong... (Joking aside, I think the advice above is spot on.)

Comment: Ahh, ok, and apparently the curve control, which I didn't for or need, effects the angle of the blade too. Thanks for the info, saved me a return :-)